# Can I use the quasi-equilibrium approximation when drug and ligand distribution volumes are different?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

A drug $D$ binds a ligand $L$ to form a complex $C$ according to the law of mass action. Furthermore, mass balance should be achieved. Can I still assume quasi-equilibrium when the distribution volumes of the drug and the ligand are different?

From the quasi-equilibrium approximation it follows that

$$k_\mathrm{on} [D] [L]=k_\mathrm{off} [C],$$

from which the dissociation constant is

$$K_\mathrm{d} = \frac{[D][L]}{[C]} = \frac{\frac{D}{V_D}\frac{L}{V_L}}{\frac{C}{V_C}},$$

with $[x]$ describing the concentrations, $x$ the amounts, and $V_x$ the distribution volumes.

Mass balance now means that

\begin{align}
D_\mathrm{tot} &= D + C &
\text{and}&&
L_\mathrm{tot} &= L + C.
\end{align}

Can I now rewrite the equation for $K_\mathrm{d}$ as

$$K_\mathrm{d} = \frac{\frac{D_\mathrm{tot}-C}{V_D}\frac{L_\mathrm{tot}-C}{V_L}}{\frac{C}{V_C}} ?$$

Even though this might be very basic, I would really appreciate if someone could explain it in detail.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). (We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.)

Comment: Evidently you have a model that is a little more complicated than a homogeneous single phase. You may want to simply declare multiple phases with independent equilibria. Or do you have flow conditions to satisfy and that is why you invoke "quasi-equilibrium"?